# listreceivedbyaddress missing transactions after restore

Tags: address, json-rpc, api

After restoring wallet from wallet.dat balance is identical,

but `listreceivedbyaddress 0` do not have the transactions associated with wallet.

`listunspent 0` show all the transactions, but it will not list anymore after spending.

is it a bug? or do i have to perform some special scan? `rescanblockchain` found all the transactions, but they are still missing in the `listreceivedbyaddress`.

**EDIT #1**

Is there a way to get all the transactions associated with specific address, what will get accurate result from blockchain? Was supposed to be bellow command what is not working sometimes.

```
listreceivedbyaddress 0 true true {ADDRESS}
```

**EDIT #2**

Output of `getaddressinfo {ADDRESS}` differences between recent, and backup wallet:

```
+  "solvable": true,
+  "desc": "sh(wpkh([6f8c0001/0'/0'/306']034e{SCRAMBLED_LONG_CODE}e50f))#ejlphmc0",
+  "ischange": true,
-  "hdmasterkeyid": "f9248{SCRAMBLED_LONG_CODE}53587b4",
+  "hdmasterfingerprint": "6f8c0001",
   "labels": [
-    {
-      "name": "default_wallet",
-      "purpose": "receive"
-    }
   ]
```

Comment: If you run `getaddressinfo` on the address whose incoming tramsactions are missing, what does it say about being change?

Comment: @PieterWuille, ```getaddressinfo``` shows that restored wallet consider address as "change"

Comment: Can you give an as detailed history of how you got into this state? It's possibly a bug that this address is being considered change.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue after restoring from wallet.dat. It's probably a bug described in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/20293. Possible way to fix it is by setting an empty label to the address that became change:

```
bitcoin-cli setlabel "{address}" ""
```

Comment: FYI, this bug should be fixed in the next release :)